# Update and Save Folder using Core service 2011

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am new to Core service.  I have a requirement to update metadata schema of a folder( from the drop down) and on successful selection of Metadata schema, I need to update the value for a field(Metadata schema) in the folder and save it.

I am able to fetch the folder and its metadata value using folder.MetadataSchema.IdRef
Tried Updating the Metadata schema of the folder  using folder.MetadataSchema.IdRef = "Metadata schema’s tcm id"; and I am getting the below error while saving it. client.Save(folder, null);

"unable to find URL/Tridion/schema/folder:Metadata"

Please help me in saving the folder and to update the dependent metadata field.

Code Snippet:

```
                   var folder = (FolderData)client.Read(tcmid, new ReadOptions());   
                   if (folder.MetadataSchema.IdRef.Equals("tcm:0-0-0"))
                   { 
                         var Schema = new LinkToSchemaData();
                        Schema.IdRef = "tcm:84-2784-8";
                        folder.Metadata = null;
                        folder.MetadataSchema = Schema;                           
                        client.Save(folder, null);                            
                    }
```

Comment: Could you add a code snippet of your core service application to indicate exactly what you did and also specify what language that is in? That will make it a lot easier to answer this question.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I have tried. Language : C#, Error : "Unable to find URL/Tridion/Schema/folder:Metadata"

Comment: Does your metadata schema have any required fields? folder.Metadata = null;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
//For updating a meta data schema of the Folder:

var client = <properly initialized core service client>;
var folder= (FolderData)client.Read(<TCM URI of the Folder>, new ReadOptions());
var new Schema = new LinkToSchemaData();
new Schema.IdRef = <TCM URI of the Schema>;
folder.Metadata = null;
folder.MetadataSchema = newSchema;
client.Save(folder, new ReadOptions());

//For updating a meta data fields:

schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields(folder.MetadataSchema.IdRef, true,
                                             DEFAULT_READ_OPTIONS);
fields = Fields.ForMetadataOf(schemaFields, folder);

 // Update Fields Accordingly
  field[<field name>].Value = <new value>;

  //Update the metadata
  folder.Metadata = fields.ToString();
  client.Save(folder, DEFAULT_READ_OPTIONS);

  //Helper Method

  public static Fields ForMetadataOf(SchemaFieldsData _data, 
                                               RepositoryLocalObjectData _item)
  {
      return new Fields(_data, _data.MetadataFields, _item.Metadata, "Metadata");
  }
```

Also, you can see more information about these great methods [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried the code that you have shared, I am still facing the same issue  "Unable to find URL/Tridion/Schema/folder:Metadata".  Also, Could you please let me know if this is a custom method'ForMetadataOf'

Comment: Its unfortunate. By the way, the ForMetadataOf is a custom method. I have added the definition of this method my answer along with the link where such useful functions has been shared.

Answer (score 2):

I think at minimum you have to set `folder.Metadata` to:

```
<Metadata xmlns="uuid:<YOUR_VALUE>"></Metadata>
```

Check that

```
folder.Metadata = fields.ToString();
```

Is setting the value correctly.

Try hard-coding the string as a test.

You can find your uuid by opening your schema, and looking at the source tab:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but getting error                            var newSchema = new LinkToSchemaData();
                                    newSchema.IdRef = "a1ee6c20-8a16-4e92-9265-9defb9bde573";
                                    newFolderData.Metadata = null;
                                    newFolderData.MetadataSchema = newSchema;

Comment: It might be best to create a new question for your problem, but this line looks wrong "newSchema.IdRef = "a1ee6c20-8a16-4e92-9265-9defb9bde573";". This should refer to the TCMID of a schema, or blank if you are dynamically creating schemas